Does WebView2 embedded browser support Microsoft's Windows PRT (primary Refresh Token)
We are currently using IdentityModel.OidcClient to connect to an OIDC Entity provider in a WPF application using the embedded WebView2 control.  This is working but does not seem to be using PRT (it does not seem to forward the x-ms-RefreshTokenCredential cookie).  I have read that the WebView2 control is NOT compatible as per https://github.com/AzureAD/MSAL.PS/issues/75#issuecomment-1618531289
I could not find any other confirmation.  Can anyone confirm this please ideally citing an official reference and/or indicate whether there are some known workarounds or alternative methods we could use?
